# What encoding should I specify in my XML file for the DOM Parser to parse Tamil, Telugu, Malayalam and other Indian regional language scripts?

Tags: java, xml, swing, encoding, utf-8

> UTF-8
>
> ISO-8859-1
>
> TACE16
>
> ISCII Tamil
>
> TSCII

I have tried all the above standards and DOM Parser cannot encode the XML file which consist of regional language scripts. 
Which encoding standard should I use for

> Tamil
>
> Telugu
>
> Malayalam
>
> Kannada

UTF-8 works well with Marathi and Hindi though.

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ihelp>
<home>வீடு</home>
</ihelp>
```

I am using DOM parser to parse the xml file.

```
System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("home").item(0).getTextContent());
```

This prints the encoded value **வீடு** in the console.

But,

```
homeButton.setText(eElement.getElementsByTagName("home").item(0).getTextContent());
```

is not printing me the string **வீடு** on button.

I am using Eclipse and working on Java Swing.

**EDIT:**

I use radio buttons to choose language. When I choose between Regional Language options and the English language option I get the following Log in the console.

> com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException:
>   Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:701)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:567)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1896)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(XMLEntityScanner.java:1551)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2821)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
>     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:205)
>     at
>   swingJava.LanguageTranslator.languageParser(LanguageTranslator.java:33)
>     at swingJava.IHelp$1.actionPerformed(IHelp.java:76)     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Unicode supports all those languages, which means so does UTF-8. What problems exactly are you encountering?

Comment: Since printing to the console works, the XML is obviously not your issue. You'll probably need to provide more context to the Java code here for somebody to be able to help you. Forget about the first part of the question. I'm not a Java person, so I can't help any further.

Comment: It seems you simply have a font issue: the font used by your button isn't able to display the characters contained in the text. Nothing to do with XML.

Comment: @JBNizet I couldn't figure out what variant of font is used in the Buttons created by swing.

Comment: When you use awt or swing, you have to specify that the text is UTF-8. As far as I used, I did saw tamil characters printed in console correctly but not in awt/swing applet. Then, I explicitly specified that the text is unicode and Mentioned that it is latha font and then got it corrected.  Like,. `Font f = new Font("Latha", 10, Bold);` then included `f` in the window object and got it corrected